# Sass to css output

Tags: css, sass

I think this is the way to do it but my css output is not what I was expecting:

**SOURCE CODE**

This is my scss file:

```
footer.page-footer
{
  margin-top: 0;
  &,
  nav
  {
    background-color: $blue;
  }
}
```

This is the css output:

```
footer.page-footer
{
  margin-top: 0;
}
footer.page-footer,
footer.page-footer nav
{
  background-color: #50a4b1;
}
```

How can I make the second outputted css's selector be simply `footer.page-footer, nav` instead of `footer.page-footer, footer.page-footer nav`?

Comment: It appears that you forgot to ask a question.

Comment: It is on the comment in the css output....

Comment: @NickBartlett, I stand corrected, although I'm not sure I'd consider `@at-root` to be shorthand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`@at-root`](http://thesassway.com/news/sass-3-3-released#at-root) directive to produce a rule that is generated outside its definition scope but that retains the value of its parent (&)

```
footer.page-footer {
  margin-top: 0;

  @at-root {
    #{&},
    nav {
      background-color: blue;
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
footer.page-footer {
  margin-top: 0;
}
footer.page-footer,
nav {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p class="sassmeister" data-gist-id="93b3b22a2888f2f5f86b" data-height="480" data-theme="tomorrow"><a href="http://sassmeister.com/gist/93b3b22a2888f2f5f86b">Play with this gist on SassMeister.</a></p><script src="http://cdn.sassmeister.com/js/embed.js" async></script>
```

[Sassmeister](http://sassmeister.com/gist/93b3b22a2888f2f5f86b)

Comment: I suppose for some really crazy selectors this might save some typing, but in this particular case it seems like the cure is worse than the disease.

Comment: True it's not super useful here, but it gets the job done.  `@at-root` does have some [pretty cool applications](http://unakravets.tumblr.com/post/64113156740/sass-3-3-at-root-bem) with more complicated use cases.